# Android horrizontal scroll gallery application

Tags: android, gallery

I want to create simple application like android image gallery but I don't want to display images. I want to display an editTexts and buttons...

My idea is to use android.widget.Gallery. Is it good way to solve this?

My next idea is HorizontalScrollView but here is problems with snaps etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you could do this with Gallery, make an Adapter that returns your layout that contains the EditText and Buttons.
However, you should check out [ViewPager](http://android-developers.blogspot.com/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html)